# Page not modified after call Ajax in MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-web-api

Hello  I am new to AJAX and MVC. I am trying to receive a data from WebAPi App in MVC to page using Jquery with AJAx but i am having problem with page is not updating the data but when i check in the output of Visual Studio  i see it received well and give the HTTP status 200 "OK" but in the page no data displayed

here goes the code of Page

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js">

    </script>
}


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type:'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:45624/api/Vehicles/',
                    datatype:'json',
                    sucess: function(data){
                        $.each(data, function (index,element) {
                            $("#grid").append("<tr><td>" + element.Maker + "</td><td>" + element.Model + "</td><td>"
                                + element.BodyType + "</td><td>" + element.Drivers + "</td><td>"
                                + element.AquisitionDate + "</td><td>" +
                                "<tr>");
                        });
            }
}


                );
        });
    </script>


<h2>All Companies</h2>

<table id="#grid"><tr>
    <td>Maker</td><td>Model</td><td>Body Type</td><td>Drivers</td>
    <td>AqusitionDate</td><td>Images</td><td>Schedules</td><td>Maintenances</td>

       </tr>

   </table>
```

i tried to use alert but nothing  when i try Google Chrome and add Error option i need to refresh 3 times to get error i am debugging with IE10

Comment: In the breowser i have the response but in my page no changes

Comment: Try $("#grid").html(...) instead of $("#grid").append(...)

Comment: NOt working the problem is with sucess  when i add error and put wrong url i have error alert 404

Comment: change <table id="#grid"> to <table id="grid">. $("#grid") selects all elements with id="grid", that's what the # means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Everytime I write some jquery ajax code, I always double-check my spelling.

They already commented about the `id="#grid"` thing, but `$.ajax` doesn't have a member called `sucess`. And `datatype` should be `dataType`. You should now notice that Javascript is Case-Sensitive.

Replace `sucess` by `success` and `datatype` by `dataType`.
Your code shoud look like this:

```
   $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type:'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:45624/api/Vehicles/',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data){
                    $.each(data, function (index,element) {
                        $("#grid").append("<tr><td>" + element.Maker + "</td><td>" + element.Model + "</td><td>"
                            + element.BodyType + "</td><td>" + element.Drivers + "</td><td>"
                            + element.AquisitionDate + "</td><td>" +
                            "<tr>");
                    });
              }
          });
    });
```

Brotip: `http://localhost:45624/api/Vehicles/` can be written as `@Url("Vehicles", "api")` I think. I dont remember which is right: `@Url("Vehicles", "api")` or `@Url("api", "Vehicles")`. You WILL use it someday, try writing this.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo and Major  Byte is working the problem was "success" and the id